# Neural Network Classifier VS Neural Network in Machine Learning Model Type

Tags: ios, machine-learning, coreml

Is there any difference between these **Neural Network Classifier** and **Neural Network** in **machine learning model** type used in **iOS** ? Whenever i create a **machine learning iOS app** with these two model type i often use **VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservatio**n for **Neural Network** and **VNClassificationObservation** for **Neural Network Classifier**. **why**?

Comment: This is pretty much the same question you asked a few days ago. And in fact, the question you're asking here is the same as my answer to that other question: a classifier gives VNClassificationObservation results, a regular neural network gives VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation results. Why? It's just a convenience for people who want to use classifiers, so they don't have to decode the prediction results themselves.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans i have some confusion in coreML and your Library. how can i contact you?

Comment: Click on my profile, go to my website. :-)